# Non-unique way of expressing vector in Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $(b_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ are linear independent set with dense span. If $b_{i}$ fail to be a Schauder basis, does that mean there exists $x\in H$ such that $x$ can be expressed non-uniquely by $b_{i}$? In other words, $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}b_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a'_{n}b_{n}$, where $a_{n}, a'_{n}$ are different.

By linear independence, I think it is quite impossible to happen, but things are weird in infinite dimension case, so I am not sure.

**Edit** Assume $x$ also takes a form $\sum_{n}\sum_{k}^{n}c_{nk}b_{k}$, can  we conclude $\sum_{n}c_{nk}=a_{k}$?

Comment: There is no guarantee that every vector $x$ is of the form $\sum a_nbn$.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171184/is-a-linearly-independent-set-whose-span-is-dense-a-schauder-basis/3171188#3171188)

Comment: @geetha290krm If $x$ has the representation $=\sum_{n}a_{n}b_{n}$, can we conclude that if $x=\sum_{n}\sum_{k}^{n}c_{nk}b_{k}$ also, then $\sum_{n}c_{nk}=a_{k}$?

Comment: The comments seem to be ignoring that the question is about uniqueness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniqueness may indeed fail.  For an example,
let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n\geq 1}$, and define, for every $n\geq 0$,
$$
  f_n=\left\{\matrix{
    \hfill\displaystyle-\frac{e_1}2, & \text{if } n=0,\cr
    e_n- \displaystyle\frac{e_{n+1}}2, & \text{if } n\geq 1,\cr
  }\right.
  $$
Then it is clear that $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a linearly independent set.  Moreover
$$
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty  2^{-n}f_n=
  -\frac{e_1}2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty  2^{-n}(e_n- \frac{e_{n+1}}2) = $$$$ =
  -\frac{e_1}2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty  2^{-n}e_n- \sum_{n=1}^\infty  2^{-(n+1)}e_{n+1} = $$$$ =
  -\frac{e_1}2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty  2^{-n}e_n- \sum_{n=2}^\infty  2^{-n}e_{n} = 0.
  $$
This provides an alternative way to represent zero besides $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  0\ f_n$.